# SerialTimeoutException in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, serial-port

Sometimes I do not get any data in via the serial interface and I want to catch this case with an exception in the following way:

```
ser          = serial.Serial(3)
ser.baudrate = 115200
timeout      = 1

while (some condidion)
  try:
    dump = ser.read(40)
  except ser1.SerialTimeoutException:
    print('Data could not be read')

ser.close()
```

However, when I run this program, the exception is never caught when no
data is in the buffer and I am stuck in an endless loop. Anyone an idea
what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Two things that may be typos / omissions in question code: 1. exception should probably be `serial.SerialTimeoutException` 2. you do not set the condition to `False` after catching the exception.

Comment: Do you ever see the message "Data could not be read"?

Comment: Nope, never saw it because the exception got never caught as glglgl explains below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't even know about that exception. After having a look at [the API documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html), you'll see that this exception only applies to `write()`.

If you `read()`, you'll just have a shortened or even empty output.

And this applies only if you have opened the connection with a timeout. Something like `serial.Serial(3, timeout=.1)`.

Comment: brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Works now ;)